# Half of Crontab script works, the other half doesn't

Tags: cron, centos6, nas

I'm having some difficulty with my Crotab.  I've run through this list: https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work Which was helpful.  I have the following crontab

```
35 02 * * * /root/scripts/backup
```

Which runs:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/home:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

echo "Time: $(date)" >> /home/me/SystemSync.log

rsync -ar -e ssh /home/ root@IPADDRESSOFNAS:/volume1/backup/server/SystemSSD/

echo "Time: $(date)" >> /SecondHD/RsyncDebug.log

sudo rsync -arv -e ssh /SecondHD/ root@IPADDRESSOFNAS:/volume1/backup/server/SecondHD/
```

The .log files are written to the server, with the intention that they will be synced with the NAS if it is successfully synced.

I know the following:

1. The SystemSSD portion of the script works as do both of the log portions of the script.  On the NAS, I see the Systemsync.log file with the newest entry.  I find the RsyncDebug.log on the server with the updated time stamp, but not on the on the NAS.
2. The script runs in its entirety when I run it from the command line, just not in crontab.

Potentially pertinent information:

1. I'm running CentOS 6 on the server.
2. The system drive is a 1TB SSD and the Second drive is a 4 TB Raid1 hard drive with ca. 1 TB of space remaining.
3. The NAS volume has 5TB drives, with about 1 TB of space remaining.

Thanks in advance.  Someday I hope to teach as much as I learn from this community.

Comment: Under what user account does your crontab script run? Maybe there are permission issues of that user. Or the user is not in the sudoers file with bash allowance.

Comment: It is run as root to avoid permissions issues.

Comment: Why do you set a path? Is this path also set after calling sudo? Maybe rsync or ssh are not found?

Comment: WeSee, If the rsync or ssh weren't found then the SSD wouldn't back up, which it does.  One drive will rsync and the other doesn't, and they both work when the script is called via command line.  I set a path becaus it was recommended in crontab troubleshooting, even though I'm specifying absolute file paths.

Comment: That's correct, but sudo starts the shell of the root user. That can be another as /bin/bash. To find out which shell is started by root see /etc/passwd. And to find out which PATH is set, see ~root/.bashrc , ~root/.profile or whichever startup script uses your shell.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Removing the sudo makes it run.